# Datacash 3DS txn cannot be authorized

Tags: payment, datacash

I've inherited a payment system on a website that uses Datacash in Iframes to take user payment.

We've seen an issue where a user gets a "3DS txn cannot be authorized" after they've authorised the payment with 3D secure. The datacash documentation says that this can be caused when "the transaction has already received a valid threedsecure_authorization_request message."

This enabled me to replicate the issue, which I wasn't able to before. The only way I can consistently replicate this is by:

1. Using the live datacash payment gateway. (The test version never throws the issue)
2. When I get to my bank authorisation page I press the confirm button multiple times as fast as possible.

When we asked DataCash whether this was an expected issue, and if they could provide a way forward on how to fix it all they said was:

"Please be informed that other merchants have achieved this by using a combination of HTML and CSS. Unfortunately, we are unable to share other merchants code or advise on web design. We would advise that you consult with your web design team.

Once the HTML has been amended, please open a new case and advise what vTIDs and pagesets need updating."

Which didn't really help at all.

What I've been able to see is that **every** time I press the "continue" button on my bank/card auth page (Visa is all I've tested) a request is sent back to the handler on our site that completes the payment. This explains the "3DS txn cannot be authorized" error; if the user gets trigger happy, the HTTP request to complete the transaction is performed multiple times.

Is there a way to prevent Datacash from calling the completion handler multiple times in short succession?

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I haven't used DataCash Payment Gateway. But, I understand that you will like to prevent multiple interaction with the button from the user's side.

You can disable the button after a single click to prevent multiple "submits".
This is probably what the DataCash Team meant by "HTML/CSS" solution.

Also, could I please request the link to the Website of this Payment Gateway and their documentation.